# Is there a good VB6 documentation system similar to Javadoc?

Tags: vb6, documentation-system

I'm working with a VB6 code base and I'm interested in beginning to generate documentation for future development efforts. I'm traditionally a Java developer and I've gotten quite used to the Javadoc system for generating such documentation. I found [VB.DOC](http://vb-doc.sourceforge.net/) but from what I can see it's meant for a .NET environment. Are there any that will work in VB6?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you seriously considering using VB6 for _future_ development?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are [a few filters](http://www.doxygen.nl/helpers.html) that will allow you to use [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) with VB6.

Answer (score 4):

I had some good time with [VbDox](http://vbdox.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: I'm a Doxygen fan, but for VB6 I think VBDOX beats Doxygen in simplicity and ease of use.

Answer (score 0):

I used [Document! X](http://www.innovasys.com/products/dx2008/overview.aspx) version 4, but I have to say it was not the most stable program to use and sometimes caused crashes in the IDE. Perhaps later versions have improved; they still seem to support VB 5&6.