# Automated Process to Extract Text from Excel to Word

Tags: excel, ms-word, automation

I need some help with a project. I work as a librarian, and we are currently undergoing a process to relabel all of our picture books. What we are working with is a long list of all our picture books in Excel, which we then copy the author's last name (in one column) and paste it into a Word Doc which is formatted in the arrangement of those Avery label templates. We have over 8000 picture books, and as you can imagine this process takes quite a bit of time, but I have a rudimentary background in code (VB, Java), and I believe this process can be automated with scripts, but I'm not quite sure how. Any advice on commands I can use or how I should organize my code would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-US/Article/Mail-merge-for-labels-276a2cd1-74d2-43d0-ab5a-b90460358ad5?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn Excel and Word COM interface. They are quite simple to use.
See some examples for Excel on Python [[in this thread]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441758/driving-excel-from-python-in-windows). For MS Word usage you just need to use 'Word.Application' object instead of 'Excel.Application'. In VB Script such objects are created with CreateObject() function: [[some examples in MSDN]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa262700(v=vs.60).aspx).

See [[Word object reference]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb225019(v=office.12).aspx) and [[Excel objects hierarchy]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25526335/vba-object-model-reference-documentation) for detailed interface descriptions.